# Error while running a batch with a file as parameter that does not belong to the current directory

Tags: batch-file, parameters, path

After several searches in INTERNET, It seems that it is obviously not possible to run a batch with a file whose path is not the same as the bat file (located at the current directory). So can you tell me if there is a workaround for this issue, without copying this file to the current directory?

For further information, please look at below the error I have got each time I ran the bat with a parameter out of my current directory. I don't understand why since echoing "%~f1" returns "D:\WorkpaceDEV\opt\ABC\IJS_002.TXT" successfully and my text file is absolutely present into the folder D:\WorkpaceDEV\opt\ABC".

```
C:\Users\bob\Desktop\DEV\Workspace>
C:\Users\bob\Desktop\DEV\Workspace>run.bat "D:\WorkpaceDEV\opt\ABC\IJS_002.TXT"
"D:\WorkpaceDEV\opt\ABC\IJS_002.TXT"
La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de répertoire ou de volume est incorrecte.
```

Here's is my origin bat file

```
     @ echo off
    echo "%~f1"
    findstr /r "I.*=" "%~f1" >outer.TXT
```

it seems to me that: the error message I have gotten is related to a configuration problem, But I am not sure! 
If it could help, I am on Seven 32. Please Let me also know if you encounter this problem on your side. If it is the case, perhaps we could conclude that it is a Bug from Microsoft?   I'm really blocked and I look forward getting from you. 
Thank you very much to open my eyes on this issue

Comment: try `run.bat "D:\WorkspaceDEV\opt\ABC\IJS_002.TXT"`

Comment: It's really "D:\WorkspaceDEV\opt\ABC\IJS_002.TXT" that I tried. Indedd The second "D:\WorkspaceDEV\opt\ABC\IJS_002.TXT" that's written come from the command prompt.

Comment: look at `WINDOWS\system32` if  `findstr.exe` exists there.

Comment: Yes, findstr exists in the system32 directory. If I am at my current directory, no problem findstr get items that I want to but I'm not in there and I have many files elsewhere.Thanks

Comment: what does it say when you remove the quotes '"' around %~f1?

Comment: the same error message happens when I remove the quotes; Moreover I have no spaces into my path, it's really painful!

Comment: If I change my origin bat by this one:
@ echo off
echo "%%~f1"
if exist "%~f1" (
   findstr /r "I.*=" "%~f1" >outer.TXT
) else (
   echo File does NOT exist!
)

Comment: I'd take a wild guess that the filename being displayed as ANSI characters is actually some Unicode string. CMD is happy with one, but `FINDSTR` can make no sense of it. Perhaps experimenting with the file's short name would be wothwhile trying - as an experiment, not a cure...

Answer (score 3):

Well, the use of `%~f1` does NOT guarantee that the file exists! If the parameter given to the Batch file includes the full path, then `%~f1` just return the same information and does not check for the existence of the file.

I suggest you to test the Batch file below:

```
@ echo off
echo "%~f1"
if exist "%~f1" (
   findstr /r "I.*=" "%~f1" >outer.TXT
) else (
   echo File does NOT exist!
)
```

Comment: sorry, it does not solve my issue. The same error message is showing from the command promt. thanks

Comment: something is very strange: the program does not go into the else conditional, since it shows the same error message that is La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de répertoire ou de volume est incorrecte.

Comment: Try changing `findstr /r "I.*=" "%~f1"` by `findstr /r /C:"I.*=" "%~f1"`

Comment: after adding /C: it's always give the same error message. my operating system is a seven 32. I don't know if this issue is own to seven and I wonder that there is no workaround??It's awful!

Answer (score 0):

echo %ComSpec% was not showed anything at prompt command . I don't know why. Therefore set it to "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" has solved the issue.

Thank you all for your investigation.